# Android - ImageView source from protected folder assets

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-xml, android-assets

I want to load images from `assets` folder into an ImageView by `XML attribute` so, in the layout. Also, i want to protect these images because is very easy decompile APK and extract files. Is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but that would be called a DRM solution (the complete solution to your problem), and nobody likes DRM.